# How to change the workbook in a recorded macro with a workbook that changes name every month

Tags: excel, vba

I´m quite new to VBA and I´m stuck with a macro. Since a lot of calculations can be done simply through Excel formulas, I just recorded a macro with them. The problem is that all these calculations are linked to workbooks that change names monthly and I would like to know if there exists a way to change only the workbook part in a  recorded macro.

I want to avoid to rewrite the formulas only with VBA because they are really a lot in many different workbooks and they are not really streightforward, so it would take a lot of time for me to code them with VBA.

Since as I said the workbooks change names every month, what I did so far was to create a code for opening all the workbooks according to the monthly names. They have all in common a part of the path called in the code "basepath" and then each will have a different ending.

I tried, without succeeding,  to put the new name of the workbook into the recorded macro but it didn´t work.

```
Dim Network As Object
Set Network = CreateObject("wscript.network")

Dim Path As String
Dim basePath As String
basePath = ‘my base path’

Dim Debtbalance _Path As String
Dim Debtbalance_Path As String
Debtbalance_Path = basePath & ‘rest of the path

Dim Debtbalance As Workbook
Set Debtbalance = Application.Workbooks.Open(Debtbalance_Path)

Windows("Test MTD.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("MTD Checks").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=ROUND(SUMIFS([Monthly Debt Balance_202307.xlsx]Sheet1!C8,[Monthly Debt
Balance_202307.xlsx] Sheet1!C14,"">=";";&R[-3]C[-3],[Monthly Debt
Balance_202307.xlsx] Sheet1!C14,""<=";";&R[-3]C[-2]),0)";
```

This is just one of all the formulas I recorded as example. I tried to substitute "Monthly Debt Balance_202307.xlsx" with the Workbook "DebtBalance".

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=ROUND(SUMIFS([" & Debtbalance.Name & "]Sheet1!C8,[" & Debtbalance.Name 
& "]Sheet1!C14,"">=""&R[-3]C[-3],[" & Debtbalance.Name & "]Sheet1!C14,""<=""&R[-3]C[-2]),0)"
```

Comment: Thank you @Jkpieterse for the quick answer but unfortunately it doesn´t work. I keep getting "Subscript out of range".  I even tried this other version but nothing.   `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=ROUND(SUMIFS(´[" & DebtBal& "]Sheet1´!C8,´[" & DebtBal& "]Sheet1´!C14,"">=";";&R[-3]C[-3],´[" & DebtBal& "] Sheet1´!C14,""<=";";&R[-3]C[-2]),0)" `

Comment: I've edited the answer as I should have used .Formula instead of .FormulaR1C1.
The error you mention is not caused by this line of code.

Comment: Duh, of course. Was looking cross eyed :-)

Comment: Yes, this is an R1C1 formula @BigBen

Comment: The code keeps stopping at that line code unfortunately with the same error message @jkpieterse

Comment: The line of code I posted is definitely wrong as it should be a formula in US syntax (comma as argument separator). Can you post the formula as it appears in your Excel cell please? But the error message you mention (subscript out of range) indicates an error on a different line of code?

Comment: I have edited the message with a revised line of code.